# Stack Overflow Data Dump: Why does Posts.Body contain HTML elements and PostHistory.Text not?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

My goal is to explore the evolution of code snippets on Stack Overflow. Therefore, I want to use data from the official [Stack Overflow data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). I noticed that table Posts.Body contains HTML elements (most importantly the code element), but table PostHistory.Text does not. Is there any possibility to get the history of a post including the HTML elements?

Example executed in [Stack Overflow Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new):

**Query:**

```
select Body from Posts where Id=100;
```

**Result:**

```
<p>That's true. <code>serialize()</code> can...
```

**Query:**

```
select Text from PostHistory where PostId=100;
```

**Result:**

```
That's true. serialize() can...
That's true. `serialize()` can..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PostHistory.Text` stores the Markdown, i.e. what you actually type in the question/answer box. If you enter supported HTML there, it will be in the Text field as well.

`Posts.Body` stores the HTML generated by parsing the Markdown. The reason is that simply that generating it on the fly (i.e. when the page is loaded) is a bad idea performance-wise.

Most data in the Data Dump (and SEDE) is copied 1-1 from the 'real' Stack Exchange database; in particular, these fields are stored in the same way.

In the end, the only way to get HTML of old revisions is to write your own [Markdown parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605434/how-would-you-go-about-parsing-markdown) (or grab an existing one from the Internet).

Comment: The Data Dump (and SEDE) are not 1-1 copies of the 'real' databases. They are cut down, simplified versions. There are a lot of tables not in them, some structural changes, as well as some data structured differently - these are done both for backwards compatibility with previous versions and to make them easier to use.

Comment: @Oded yes, that's right. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I can see. The `PostHistory` holds the markdown, not the HTML that was rendered. The  `Posts` table though just hold the rendered HTML.

In the database there are two columns: one for the raw Markdown and one for the rendered HTML.

As you can see the revisions don't hold HTML, which is logical from a developer perspective. The current revision of the post has to be shown on-screen. Hence the HTML rendering. Revisions don't have to be shown rendered, so there is no need for them to be in HTML.

---

The problem with your query is that you are looking to two different revisions. If you would compare the code of the HTML and its markdown, then you would see:

```
<p>That's true. <code>serialize()</code> can...
```

and

```
That's true. `serialize()` can...
```